# How can I send data by ajax through codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I used this `jQuery` with `ajax`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#afilm').click(function(){
            var catdata={iddd:'9',ajax: '1'};

            $.ajax({
                url:"<?=site_url('site/ajax');?>",
                type : 'POST',
                data : catdata,
                success : function (msg){
                     alert(msg);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        </script>
```

why it doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't return any alert containing the fetching data from model through the controller

Comment: ever thought about using `$(document).load(function(){......});`?? if the browser trys to execute JS before the whole page is loaded then it might happen that the click event won't be attached to the element you want because it doesn't exist yet

Comment: If you are using FF, install FireBug add-on. Click F12, and check console if it fires and try to get data from the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
alert(msg.responseText);
```

In jQuery the response is a XMLHttpRequest Object.